# accessing bar code reader in silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

We want to develop an application in which  user can enter data with bar code reader (attached to the end user's machine).

Please suggest which client side technology we should use our website is in asp.net, should we go with Silverlight or ActiveX control.

Any sample/help or link to third party control will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

A modern barcode reader is seen by the system as a keyboard and there are no special security settings for it. That means you can use any technology to develop the application (ASP.NET, Silverlight, etc).
You do not need a sample: just read the barcode scanner installation instructions (they are usually short), connect your barcode scanner to your computer, open notepad and then scan a barcode. You should see the scanned barcode in notepad.

Comment: Also note that barcode scanners have a multitude of configurations - for instance they can cause the enter or tab key to be pushed after a code has been completed, which is helpful for integration.